# ASP.NET MVC 4 Editor Template and jQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am using a jquery datepicker in my ASP.NET MVC4 Web app. I am also using an editor template for my datetime data type.

My editor template looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" class="date" value='@(((DateTime)Model).ToShortDateString())' />
```

My code for jquery date picker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".date").datepicker();
})
```

The problem I am running into is that when I load date from the database, the date picker highlights today's date instead of the date in the textbox. How do I get the date picker to highlight the date I loaded into the textbox?

Comment: This doesn't help me since I don't know what the date will be ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".date").datepicker({defaultDate: "@(((DateTime)Model).ToShortDateString()"});
```

Surely though, if you have set @model DateTime at the top of your editor template, you could simply go:

```
$(".date").datepicker({defaultDate: "@Model.ToShortDateString()"});
```

Or in fact, maybe even dynamically like so - N.B. the id attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" class="date" value='@(((DateTime)Model).ToShortDateString())' />

$(".date").datepicker({defaultDate: $("#@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName").val()});
```

Have a play around.